# XPath to select element based on childs child value returning multiple values?

Tags: xml, xpath

So I'm following an example from another question, which I'll replicate here:

"Trying to select an element based on the value of one of it's children's children"

```
./book[author/name = 'John']
```

"Want all books where the author name = 'John'

Xml file"

```
<list>
   <book>
      <author>
        <name>John</name>
        <number>4324234</number>
      </author>
      <title>New Book</title>
      <isbn>dsdaassda</isbn>
   </book>
   <book>...</book>
   <book>...</book>
</list>
```

Now, for whatever reason, when I use the xpath above, it DOES select the book node, but it selects all of them, not just the one where author = John. Is there a reason why the xpath would be ignoring that and just pulling every book node?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it selects all `book` nodes? Your xpath looks ok

Comment: @AlehDouhi Admittedly, I'm working with xpath through a Ruby gem that maps XML to Ruby objects. However, the documentation is slim, and it doesn't seem to be very widespread. I was hoping The XML example was missing something, but I think you're right. That XPath should work, but in the context of my Ruby application it's just grabbing everything. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
/list/book[author/name/. = 'John']
```

or

```
/list/book[author/name/text() = 'John']
```